# Setting up elasticsearch; 2 nodes in the same machine

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I would like to know if we can deploy logstash, elasticsearch and kibana in the same machine and also setting up 2 nodes of elasticsearch in this machine.
The idea is I want to give 31Go Ram for each node and 4Go Ram to Logstash and let 30Go free.
I have a machine with 8vCPUs,96Go Ram and 250GB HDD.

Do you think is a good idea? and my logstach could index files from 10 filebeat running on 10 servers?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can deploy logstash, elasticsearch and kibana in the same machine as long as you have enough resource in your machine to support it. All depends on the data you have to work on and available resources.

Comment: I can have enough resource just I would like to know If it's necessary to deploy two nodes of elasticsearch or only one? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it perfectly makes sense to make multiple nodes of elasticsearch though you have single machine. Refer to this for detail overview: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/can-i-run-multiple-elasticsearch-nodes-on-the-same-machine/67

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends to your usage, type of your nodes. data, master, cordinating only, ingest node?

Read this documentation, you will have idea about nodes: [Nodes|Elasticsearch Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html)

A benefit of having master node on different machines is about the handling failover scenarios for cluster management.
Having data nodes on different machines will give you data replication elasticity, by sharing shards on different machines it will distribute executions. In my opinion there is no any rationale having es nodes in the same machine.

A few advice:

Elasticsearch uses filesystem cache for I/O operations, which means "you should make sure that at least half the available memory goes to the filesystem cache".

Increase index memory buffer size: [Index Buffer|Elasticsearch Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indexing-buffer.html)

Increase index thread pool size: [Thread Pool|Elasticsearch Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html)

Comment: In fact I can't have to separate machine to made two nodes I can only have one machine so that makes sense to deploy two nodes that shared the same hard disk or just only can handle  30GO of data per day! I would like to store data for 6-7 days. I could have only a large machine with enough RAM and CPU as I want but not having two machines. So you suggest me to deploy one or two nodes? Thanks again